# Expanding the energy-momentum relation of a relativistic particle

Tags: taylor-expansion, physics, mathematical-physics

I need to expand the equation:

$$E^2 = p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4$$

to the fourth term according to the momentum (p)

My question is, usually when expanding something in a Taylor series, I am given that something is much smaller relative to something else, allowing me to use the series. Here I am just told to expand, and would appreciate some direction

Comment: Can you post the exact wording of what you want to do?

Comment: Maybe my issues comes from not understanding the question either.

I need to expand the relation into a series until the fourth term for a relativistic particle for/according to the momentum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a particle of mass $m_0$, this equation can be rewritten as

$$
E = m_0c^2 \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{p}{m_0 c} \right)^2}
$$

The expansion you're looking for is in the variable $x = p/m_0c$, which is basically the speed of the particle in units of $c$, $x = v/c$, so the only thing you need is to know how to expand $\sqrt{1 + x^2}$:

$$
\sqrt{1 + x^2} \approx 1 + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{8}
$$

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
E &\approx& m_0c^2\left[1 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{p}{m_0 c} \right)^2 - \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{p}{m_0 c} \right)^4\right] \\
&=& m_0c^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_0v^2 - \frac{1}{8c^4}m_0v^4
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

It is helpful to think in terms of dimensional analysis: The only independent physical quantity in this problem which has units of momentum besides $p$ is $m_0c$. Hence for this expansion to make sense we should really be expanding in powers of $p/m_0c$. To make this more familiar, note that in special relativity we have $$\frac{p}{m_0 c}=\frac{\gamma m_0 v}{m_0c}=\frac{v/c}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}.$$
For this to be small, we need $v/c$ to be small as well i.e. the system is non-relativistic for speeds much smaller than the speed of light.